# to print and count number of matching vowels in a pair of strings

Tags: python

hey guys I got this question on a test , has been bugging me for days now . best i could come up with was to convert it into sets and use set intersection , but that gives consnants too plus it does not tell how many times the vowel is occuring .

```
a="Asish"
b="Sankar"
a = list(a.lower())
#print(a)
b = list(b.lower())
a = set(a)
b = set(b)
print(a &b)
```

expected output:
number of matching vowel cases are :0

sample input 2-
a=Asish
b=sashank
sample output-
a
number of times matching vowels occured - 1

Comment: Please post your attempted code.

Comment: [edit] your post and add the expected output, and maybe a second example

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? To me, when you say *matching*, the first thing that comes to mind is *"letters in matching indexes"* but it doesn't seem like there are any in your example. Can you clarify?

Comment: i am sorry for not clarifying , the question asks to find the common vowels in both strings and also tell the number of times that particular vowel occurs in both strings.

Answer (score 0):

My Approach will be like this:

```
a = "Aasish"
b = "Sankiar"
a = a.lower()
b = b.lower()
vowels_count = 0
repeat_count = []
for i in a:
    if i in b:
        if i in "aeiou" and i not in repeat_count:
            print("Matching Vowels:", i)
            print(f"Vowel '{i}' appeared total of {int(a.count(i)) + int(b.count(i)) } times in two strings.")
            repeat_count.append(i)
```

Output:

```
Matching Vowels: a
Vowel 'a' appeared total of 4 times in two strings.
Matching Vowels: i
Vowel 'i' appeared total of 2 times in two strings.
```

Comment: hi sir ! your code counts the number of vowels in both strings , the question asks for the number of times a single vowel appears in both strings , i.e. a="all" , b="antares" . here the output would be common vowel is a in both and it is commonly appearing just once . in a way we have to use logic similar to sets intersection.

Comment: `for i in a: if i in a`... why? If `i` is the loop variable of `a`, then of course it is `in a`... No need to check that

Comment: Edit the Line 11: print(f"Vowel '{i}' appeared {a.count(i)} times in {a} and {b.count(i)} times in {b}")